# How can I create access denied folder in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi

How can I create an access denied folder or file by Delphi?

I would like only myself to be able to access that folder/file from delphi.

Comment: IN modern versions of Windows changing file permissions on a folder from your own application might get blocked by the operating system. Nevertheless, the JEDI API library / JEDI Security Code Library might help you.  Check the demos that come with JWSCL here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a file under your user profile. The default security settings disallow other users access. Naturally administrators have access but you can't hide from an administrator.

Comment: see this link about ShGetSpecialFolderPath: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/mydocuments.htm

Answer (score 3):

you can try my simplified example

```
interface
...
   function EncryptFileA(lpFilename: PAnsiChar): BOOL; stdcall;
   {$EXTERNALSYM EncryptFileA}
...
implementation
...
   // Delphi wrongly register function EncryptFileA under kernel32.dll. 
   // Just re-register it using AdvApi32.dll 
   function EncryptFileA; external AdvApi32 name 'EncryptFileA'; 
...
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateDirectory('c:\test', nil);
  EncryptFileA('c:\test');
end;
```

This code will create 'C\test' folder and encrypt it. Any file you put in it can only be accessed by owner (you). You can switch and login under different user, and test it. Of course you need to elaborate my code above to check if directory exists, get error (if any) and deal with it properly.

Or, you can use free encryption tools www.truecrypt.org and Delphi Truecrypt components, such as http://www.sdean12.org/SDeanComponents.htm#OTFETrueCrypt or google for other Delphi Truecrypt component. However, I never try this one.

Comment: I test my code with D7 on Win Xp SP3. It creates the encrypted folder (shown in green font under Win explorer). Then I create a simple text file and copy some existing files to that folder. I still can access them using my current user, but when I switched to other user, the files are not accessible (could not read, write, delete). Could you elaborate 'doesn't work'? Is it compile error or runtine error or ...?

Comment: added truecrypt stuff in my answer